# Create array in array python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

| ID | Date | Rank | Info - |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 12/5 | 1 | Anne |
| 12 | 12/5 | 2 | Louis |
| 12 | 12/5 | 3 | Nico |
| 12 | 12/5 | 4 | Vic |
| 13 | 15/5 | 2 | Stephanie |
| 13 | 15/5 | 3 | Athene |
| 13 | 15/5 | 4 | Louis |

**How can I create an array 'Rank' with condition same id and date?**

*Solution:*  [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
res = df.groupby(["ID", "Date"])["Rank"].agg(list).tolist()
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Alternative if [`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) of list is the expected output:

```
res = df.groupby(["ID", "Date"])["Rank"].agg(list).to_numpy()
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[list([1, 2, 3, 4]) list([2, 3, 4])]
```

Comment: You are correct, but I want to point that what you are calling arrays really are lists. If you want to use arrays you must import `array` module or use NumPy arrays. You can find more information about difference between lists and arrays in [this](https://learnpython.com/blog/python-array-vs-list/) link.